# how to pass in eOpts in add() method in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am writing :

```
mystore.add(mystore,{
        name: "winston fan",
        twitter: 'WFC'
    });


    mystore.on('addrecords', function(store, records, eOpts) {
        console.log('new recorded have been added.');
        console.log('new recorded number = ' + store.getCount());

        console.log(eOpts.length);
    });
```

As the Sencha Touch doc mentioned, calling add() method triggers addrecords event.

So I wonder how to pass in the eOpts?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
mystore.on('eventName', function, records, eOpts);
```

Comment: That answer doesn't make any sense. The documentation lists the parameters you can pass when binding listeners.

Comment: hi @EvanTrimboli if you tried, you would know my point. or may be you can provide your code to show your point.